Lee Smooth Manifolds Exercise 12.20
I'm trying to do exercise 12.20 from Jack M. Lee's Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, wherein we are asked to prove the following theorem:
Theorem 12.19: (Smoothness criteria for Tensor Fields)
Let $M$ be a smooth manifold with or without boundary, and let $A : M \rightarrow T^k(T^*M)$ be a rough section. Then the following are equivalent:'
(a). $A$ is smooth.
(b). In every smooth coordinate chart, the component functions of $A$ are smooth.
(c). Each point of $M$ is contained in some coordinate chart in which $A$ has smooth component functions.
(d). If $X_1, \cdots, X_k \in \mathfrak{X}(M)$, then the function $A(X_1, \cdots, X_k) : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ defined by $$ A(X_1, \cdots, X_k)(p) = A_p(X_1|_p, \cdots, X_k|_p) $$ is smooth.
(e). Whenever $X_1, \cdots, X_k$ are smooth vector fields defined on some open subset $U \subset M$, the function $A(X_1, \cdots, X_K)$ is smooth on $U$.
I'm trying to prove this by proving the chain of implications (a) $\implies$ (b) $\implies$(c) $\implies$(d) $\implies$(e).
In particular, I wanted to verify the (c) $\implies$ (d) argument.
My reasoning:
Assume (c). Then, for any $p \in M$ there exists a chart $(U, (x^i))$ centered at $p$ in which $A$ has smooth component functions. Namely, for any point $q \in U$,
$$ A(q) = A_{i_1 \cdots i_k}(q) dx^{i_1} \otimes dx^{i_k}$$ where each of the component functions $A_{i_1 \cdots i_k}(q) dx^{i_1}$  is smooth.
Now, for $q \in U$, smooth vector fields $X_1, \cdots, X_k \in \mathfrak{X}(U) \approx \mathfrak{X}(M)$ can be written as
$$ X_i = X_i^j(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_q $$
for smooth $X_i^j(q)$. Then, the function we've defined gives
$$ A(X_1, \cdots, X_k)(q) = A_q(X_1|_q, \cdots, X_k|_q) \\ = A_q\left(X_1^j(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_q, \cdots,  X_k^j(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_q\right) \\ = A_{i_1 \cdots i_k} dx^{i_1} \otimes dx^{i_k} \left(X_1^j(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_q, \cdots,  X_k^j(q) \frac{\partial}{\partial x^j}|_q \right) \\ = A_{i_1 \cdots i_k}^l X_l^j(q)$$
and since each of the terms in the last expression is a smooth function, so is the function $A : M \rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ overall.
It would be greatly appreciated if any mistakes / abuse of notation and suggestions for improvement could be pointed out. Thank you in advance!
